# Connect bottleless water dispenser to this water installation?

Tags: water, water-heater, installation

I have a bottleless water dispenser with a thin blue tube that connects to the water source. I have an area for the dispenser, but I don't know what water connector I have to purchase to make it work.

Any help is appreaciated.

Water dispenser

[image]

This is where blue tube will be conected

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hard to tell sizes from your pictures so you'll have to adapt this answer to the actual sizes of your fittings.

Assuming the blue pipe is 3/8 inch PEX, and the fitting highlighted here is a 1/2 inch hose connected to a 1/2 inch threaded nipple:
[image: OP's connection point.]

Then one way to do this would be to insert, at that connection point, another threaded Tee, another threaded nipple (to reconnect the existing metal braided hose) and a suitable adapter with a 3/8 inch Pex barb attachment:

[image: copper threaded tee]
[image: copper threaded nipple]
[image: 1/2 inch thread to 3/8 inch barb adapter]

That last piece, the barb adapter for your blue hose, may be done other ways, e.g. a 1/2 inch threaded to 3/8 inch sharkbite adapter:
[image: threaded to sharkbite adapter]

All this assumes that blue hose is of some standard size like 3/8" that will work with these fittings.  Check the documentation with the dispenser.

You should also have a shutoff valve somewhere in this scheme.  I can't tell where because I can't tell which way water flows in and out.  Add it the same way, using similar logic.  If water flows out through the wall behind the tap and then up through that red valve then that red valve may be all you need.